# Robotdyn esp8266 interrupt from arduino timing

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I use a Robotdyn, uno+wifi r3 atmega328p+esp8266. I need to control motor speed and operate few servos. Since the uno has a single timer, I use the esp8266 pin 2 to control motor speed, while the arduino pins to control servos.

I've used the serial channel for uno to send a list of speeds to operate the motors to the esp.
Now I need to trigger esp to change from one speed to another, and I was considering using one of the uno pins to trigger an interrupt for the esp, for this notification. I need the speed change as instantaneous as possible. I am using I2C 5v to 3.3v logic level converter for raising the interrupt from uno pin to pin 4 of esp.

Now the question, how long should I hold the uno pin high for the interrupt to be detected? A quick filp;
digitalWrite(outGoingIntrPin, HIGH);
digitalWrite(outGoingIntrPin, LOW);

seems to sporadically work. I think I need to introduce a delay between these statements, but I do not know how much should that delay be.

Any suggestions to improvise is welcome.

Comment: The Uno has 3 Timers in total. Considering that Timer0 is used for `delay()`/`millis()` and another timer for the servo library you have still one Timer left to operate your (I suspect 2) DC motors